# hystrix first request error fallback

Tags: hystrix, circuit-breaker

What if requestVolumeThreshold is not configured explicitly? It is calling my fallback method immediately when first request itself is error? Should the fallback method is called by 21th request?(as default requestVolumeThreshold=20, errorThresholdPercentage=50%, metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to distinguish the condition for fallback and the condition for the circuit open.

**The fallback method** of your circuit breaker will be called under the following condition

- circuit open
- semaphore/thread pool rejection
- execution fail (any exception thrown by your method excluding `HystrixBadRequestException`)
- timeout of your method (hystrix timeout)

As you can see, circuit open is just one condition for executing fallback method.

The properties that you wrote in the questions are related to circuit open, and they are not directly related to determine fallback execution.

As a result, the fallback execution for your first request will be decided by exception and timeout. Because, at this moment, definitely the circuit is closed state and your thread pool (or semaphore) is empty.

Comment: Yes. Misunderstood the concept of fallback. Thank you